# Getting 'Forbidden error' browsing a page in localhost with permission to read, write and execute

Tags: permissions, webserver

I guess there's something I'm missing here but I need to solve this in order to feel confident while learning how unix/linux OS work.

I've seen some similar questions on this topic but I don't think they solve my problem since both my users have the same privileges.

I have a localhost in my machine.

Inside my var/www/html/ directory I have directory_A created as 'root' user with a web project I developed in it. It works perfectly.

I also have directory_B which I downloaded from github to test a project with my regular user let's say 'regular_user' and I get the following error:

```
**Forbidden**

You don't have permission to access /drectory_B/ on this server.
```

So i check my permissions on both directories and compare them:

```
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Jul 13 20:25 directory_A
drwx------ 5 regular_user regular_user 4096 Jul 13 20:47 directory_B
```

So I can see my user has permission to read, write and execute. What am I missing here? Why do I get this error when browsing directory_B when I'm supposed to have permission and I don't get it when browsing directory_A when root user has the same permissions as regular_user against this file?

Comment: Just reading between the lines here, but is the "Forbidden" error coming from a web server, while the `ls` output is coming from the local system? The answer to that will point to the eventual answer of users and permissions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you access the directory via a server/browser combination of any kind, your credentials are not shared, so the server does not know that the person accessing the files is you. Try

```
chmod a+x directory_B
```

and

```
chmod a+r directory_B/*
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm going to mark yours as the good one because you answered first although I can see both are correct.

Comment: Actually, you probably want `chmod -R a+rx directory_B`.  The answer given here probably won't work if you have subdirectories within `directory_B`.  The `-R` flag ensures that `chmod` will traverse all subdirectories as well.

Comment: @D.W. Rather `chmod -R a+rX directory_B`, so as not to make all files executable.

Comment: good one guys thanks, i was facing the same problem.